# Unable to click master page button in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have put sign out button in master page. I have a page in which I use that master page and I also have update panel in this page. When I click on sign out button , it does not work. When I use anchor tag it works but I want to use Button.

Thanks,

Comment: show us your code - both from the aspx file and the aspx.vb (or aspx.cs) files

Answer (score 1):

this might be happen if you are using requiredfield validations for some input fields. try

> CausesValidation="false"

for the button control and check. hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved deleting the main div nested in the asp Content placeholder. For me all the controls inserted in the masterpage was freezed, buttons, dropdown box, all in other words.